# Is "filter" a Reserved Word in Angular, Javascript, or ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am making this call from a service using angularJS to an ASP.Net MVC controller:

```
$http({
    method: "get",
    url: "ControllerMethod",
    params: {
        param1: param1Value,
        pageNumber:  pageNumber,
        pageSize: pageSize,
        filter: filter
    }
}).success(function (data) {
    callback(data);
}).error(function () {
    alert("Error.");
});
```

The controller signature is:

```
public ActionResult GetAssetDepreciationList(
     int pageNumber, int pageSize, int param1, MyFilterType filter)
```

When run as shown, the "filter" parameter always arrives as null.  I have a number of similar methods that works without issue.

When I changed:

```
 filter: filter
```

to:

```
anythingElse : filter
```

it worked as expected.  Is "filter" a reserved word?  If so, for which framework (MVC, Javascript, or angular)?

Comment: there is something like `filter` in angular: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Comment: ngFilter shouldn't affect http. Try capturing it with Fiddler; what does the generated GET URL look like in the working and non-working cases?

Comment: Yeah, I familiar with filtering in angular.  Shouldn't interfere with http as you said.  I will check out the request.

Comment: Could it be another js library causing the issue? I don't think it's AngularJS or ASP.NET MVC or Javascript. Open up the console in your browser and type `filter`. Does the variable exist?

Comment: Hmm, the request looks identical either way it's named.

Comment: Will tinker more tomorrow.  The querystring seems to be passed correctly, all the way into the controller method.  It must be a modelBinder problem.

Comment: Cool problem I updated my answer with a solution I found.. Though not the greatest. Strange that modelbinder isn't working for json in the query string.. Could be an encoding issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your filter is of complex type `MyFilterType` Have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-bind-to-custom-objects-in-action-signatures-in-mvc-webapi.aspx)

You might need to create a custom parser. If you want to avoid that You can also keep the model (that is if MyFilterType is a POCO) and pass the filter (as JSON) with the body of the request.

Also if your filter is so complex I would suggest OData. Since you're already using .NET its a simple Nuget Package that makes your queries, its standardized and parsers already exist, plus it is configurable and can be applied directly to an IQueryable.

Some more useful information might be.. What is `MyFilterType` and what is the data actually in `:filter`.

#### update:

Interesting issue I think it has to do with the query string and model parsing... I was able to get it to work by... the following: (Need `System.Web.Http`)

```
 public ActionResult GetAssetDepreciationList(
      int pageNumber, int pageSize, int param1, [FromUri] MyFilterType filter)
```

and flattening the individual parameter names of filter, onto the params so..

```
params: angular.extend({
                           param1: paramValue,
                           pageNumber: pageNumber,
                           pageSize: pageSize,
                        },filter)
```

I assumed `var filter = {paramA:1,paramB:2,paramC:3};`

Comment: This would not explain why it works if I name the parameter one way, and fails to work when I name it another way.  The problem seems to be with the name of the parameter (on the javascript http side).

Comment: So when you're renaming you also rename `MyFilterType filter` to `MyFilterType anythingElse` and it works?

Comment: No, sorry--the way I phrased it was confusing.  I only changed it on the javascript side.

Comment: filter is an instance of MyFilterType when I name the parameter anythingElse on the js side.  It is null when I name it "filter".  MyFilterType is just a poco with three integer properties.

Comment: Hmm.. Perhaps its not parsing the JSON in the query string... (Humor me and try it on the `data` property of the `$http` config?) eg. just set `data: filter`

Comment: I'll have to look into it more tomorrow.  "data" is only going to work for POSTs, where this is a GET.

Comment: The link you posted is for custom parsing of objects--the default modelbinder should handle my scenario without issue.

Comment: This was a red herring--the problem is indeed that it's a complex type, which won't work with a GET.